# Xamarin Expander, Collectionview, and Swipeview

Tags: xamarin.forms, expander, swipeview

I am struggling with the design of a UI that has three distinct groupings:

1. Top 3
2. Friends
3. All contacts

Subscribed and All contacts are going to be big lists. My first pass at this is as follows:

```
    <Expander>
    <Expander.Header>
        <Label
            FontAttributes="Bold"
            FontSize="Medium"
            Text="Top 3" />
    </Expander.Header>
    <Expander.Content>
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding MyContacts}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <SwipeView>
                            <SwipeView.LeftItems>
                                <SwipeItem BackgroundColor="Aquamarine" Text="Un Favorite" />
                            </SwipeView.LeftItems>
                            <SwipeView.Content>
                                <Label Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
                            </SwipeView.Content>
                        </SwipeView>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </Expander.Content>
</Expander>
<Expander>
    <Expander.Header>
        <Label
            FontAttributes="Bold"
            FontSize="Medium"
            Text="Friends" />
    </Expander.Header>
    <Expander.Content>
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding UppContacts}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <SwipeView>
                            <SwipeView.LeftItems>

                                <SwipeItem BackgroundColor="Brown" Text="Fav" />

                            </SwipeView.LeftItems>
                            <SwipeView.Content>
                                <Label Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
                            </SwipeView.Content>
                        </SwipeView>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </Expander.Content>
</Expander>
```

But I can't seem to put more than one expander in a page. When I do one at a time - all works as expected.

Comment: use a TabbedPage, or use segmented control to create the illusion of a tabbed interface.  Cramming too much UI into a mobile screen is usually a bad idea

Comment: Put expander into another layout under [BindableLayout.ItemTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62573006/xamarin-forms-how-to-set-a-list-of-items-as-the-expander-child)

Comment: @Timothy **I can't seem to put more than one expander in a page**, you mean that you just can add one Expander in page? I can add more than one Expander in a page with the latest xamarin.forms version.

Comment: it would help if u can draw it out in paint how u actually planning to show up the ui

Comment: As well as my answer below it is also worth noting that the Expander control has been moved out into the Xamarin Community Toolkit. So you may want to look into using that. It can be found here: https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say you cannot have more than one expander on the page, do you mean that you are getting an error message, saying something along the lines of "The property "Content" has been set more than once"?

If that's the case then you can resolve this simply, by wrapping all of the expanders inside a container.

For example:

```
<StackLayout>
        <Expander>
            <Expander.Header>
                <Label
                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                    FontSize="Medium"
                    Text="Top 3" />
            </Expander.Header>
            <Expander.Content>
                <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding MyContacts}">
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackLayout>
                                <SwipeView>
                                    <SwipeView.LeftItems>
                                        <SwipeItem BackgroundColor="Aquamarine" Text="Unfavorite" />
                                    </SwipeView.LeftItems>
                                    <SwipeView.Content>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
                                    </SwipeView.Content>
                                </SwipeView>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
            </Expander.Content>
        </Expander>
        <Expander>
            <Expander.Header>
                <Label
                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                    FontSize="Medium"
                    Text="Friends" />
            </Expander.Header>
            <Expander.Content>
                <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding UppContacts}">
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackLayout>
                                <SwipeView>
                                    <SwipeView.LeftItems>

                                        <SwipeItem BackgroundColor="Brown" Text="Fav" />

                                    </SwipeView.LeftItems>
                                    <SwipeView.Content>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
                                    </SwipeView.Content>
                                </SwipeView>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
            </Expander.Content>
        </Expander>
    </StackLayout>
```